# Listing all primes below N using Euclid infinitude of prime proof

Tags: python, primes, sage

Here is the question:

> Write a function that accepts a bound N, and finds the first N
>   primes as determined by the classical proof of the infinitude of the set
>   of primes. That is: begin with P = {2}; then form, m, the sum of
>   1 with the product over all elements of P. Place the smallest prime
>   factor of m into P and repeat.

And here is what I did:

```
def get_primes(n):
    i = 2
    prime_list = []
    while i < n:
        p = prod(prime_list)+1
        r = min_symbolic(prime_divisors(p))
        prime_list.append(r)
        i = i+1
   return prime_list
```

It gave me a bunch of errs when I tried get_primes(10), what did I do wrong here? I just started learning python, thanks.

EDIT: sorry for not being clear, here are the errors I'm getting

```
Error in lines 1-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/projects/3fe731e3-2b4d-43b9-86a0-5efb4456f029/.sagemathcloud/sage_server.py", line 881, in execute
exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
File "", line 1, in <module>
File "", line 6, in get_primes
File "/projects/sage/sage-6.9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/rings/arith.py", line 2538, in prime_divisors
return [p for p,_ in factor(n)]
TypeError: 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `bunch of errs` can you be more specific? Which errors? on which line ? Did you try to understand them?

Comment: What is `prod`, `min_symbolic` and `prime_divisors`? Please give a [MCVe](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Alex.S: those are built-in Sage functions.  The question should still specify exactly the errors seen, but it does mention in the title and the tags that it's in the Sage environment.

Comment: Added some clarification, thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `prod` probably isn't actually factorable in the first event.  Check what happens with `prod([])+1`.  I'm on a train or I'd check this for you myself.  Also, I'm not sure why you can't just use `min`, `min_symbolic` is really only for things like `min_symbolic(x,x^2)`; you are just looking for the min of some integers so the built-in Python `min` should (?) work okay.

Answer (score 0):

kcrisman is correct that the error comes from using min_symbolic.  Replacing it with min gets rid of the error, but the code still needs to be tweaked a bit to give the first n primes as described:

```
def get_primes(n):
    prime_list = [2]
    i = 1
    while i < n:
        p = prod(prime_list) + 1
        r = min(prime_divisors(p))
        prime_list.append(r)
        i = i + 1
    return prime_list
```